# PHP message: PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function mcrypt_get_block_size()

Tags: php

```
function encryptValue($inputVal,$secureKey){

$key='';
for ($i=0; $i < strlen($secureKey)-1; $i+=2)
{
    $key .= chr(hexdec($secureKey[$i].$secureKey[$i+1]));
}

$block = mcrypt_get_block_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
$pad = $block - (strlen($inputVal) % $block);
$inputVal .= str_repeat(chr($pad), $pad);

$encrypted_text = bin2hex(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $inputVal, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB));


return $encrypted_text;
```

}
I am getting error

> PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function
>   mcrypt_get_block_size()
>   how can i resolve this ??

Comment: `mcrypt` is not enable or install on your server.

Comment: @hardiksolanki i installed using                                                                            sudo apt-get install mcrypt php5-mcrypt
  sudo php5enmod mcrypt
  sudo service nginx restart

Comment: Did you check it enable or not?

Comment: @hardiksolanki yes i checked .

Comment: Can you put your `phpinfo` screenshot here?

Comment: *If* on Ubuntu 14.04, there was a bug where the symlink was not created so the enmod didn't work. Eg: https://davekz.com/mcrypt-php-fpm-ubuntu/

Answer (score 0):

first check which library install in local server using this code

```
<?php
echo phpinfo()?;
?>
```

then check that is it install or not if not then install it

```
sudo apt-get install mcrypt php5-mcrypt
sudo php5enmod mcrypt
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

you don't forget to enable it. hope everything now working fine.

Note : This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 7.1.0. Relying on this function is highly discouraged.

for more information

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-get-block-size.php